# Rails webpacker OpenLayers. Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined. Fixed but not solved

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, openlayers-3

Complete error:

```
layerSwitcherDemo.js:52 Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/layerSwitcherDemo.js (layerSwitcherDemo.js:52)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./app/javascript/packs/layerSwitcherDemo.js @   layerSwitcherDemo.js:52
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @   bootstrap:83
(anonymous)
```

This is called from `people/show.html.erb` via `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'layerSwitcherDemo' %>`.

If I use the same `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'layerSwitcherDemo' %>` from `map/ol_layer_switcher.html.erb` the script works fine.

```
// javascript/packs/layerSwitcherDemo.js
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import { transform } from 'ol/proj';
import LayerGroup from 'ol/layer/Group';
import LayerImage from 'ol/layer/Image';
import LayerTile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import SourceOSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import XYZ from 'ol/source/XYZ';
import LayerSwitcher from 'ol-layerswitcher';
import {transformExtent, fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';

var <a long list>

// the next line is line 52 in the error      
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
// rest of the code
```

I'm trying to build up slowly to make an OpenLayers map. I'll use something different than LayerSwitcherDemo which I made just to make sure it would load in Rails. Layer Switcher is a demo that I modified.

Just thought to compare the compiled layerSwitcherDemo-xx.js script and all 55k lines are identical. application-xx.js are identical.

Fixed now but not solved. The page that was working loaded the CDN version of OpenLayers. Being new to Webpack I'm not sure which is best. I guess it's less code I'm carrying along. Let the CDN do it. This will be a very lightly used app. I'm guessing I need some kind of definition equivalent to `import $ from 'jquery'`

Comment: Thank you @rossta. I missed that was what is going on. At first I did just what you said and got an error, but realized I had a whole bunch of those to fix. For a beginner at this it was probably easier to use `import Map from 'ol/Map'` but then I have one that reads `import {transformExtent, fromLonLat} from 'ol/proj';` where the abstraction probably helps. Yours was one of the blogs that I read to get me going. Another comment to follow. So up and running.

Comment: @rossta. Is there a way to use my original notation? I guess I can go back and undo the changes and remove the import and see what happens. OK I did and obviously `ol` has to be defined somewhere. Would I have to define each ol/<whatever> to make it work? I'm going to have to understand webpacker better as well as OpenLayers. And maybe JavaScript!

Comment: @rossta. I just skimmed your https://rossta.net/blog/from-sprockets-to-webpack.html and it appears to answer my question that I'd have to define each `ol/xx`. But your post is way over my head, but I should give it another try.

Comment: Added an alternative import to my answer below based on the main entry point as reference: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/f08a2ab3d1dc3582dda2ad4e9c606924cb82bc17/src/ol/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you're calling `ol.Map`, but you've imported `Map`. Edit your Webpack JS as follows:

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map'

// ... other imports

const map = new Map({   // replaces ol.Map
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
// ...
```

OR, the following will work for *some* imports according to the [main entry point in the the openlayer module](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/f08a2ab3d1dc3582dda2ad4e9c606924cb82bc17/src/ol/index.js).

```js
import * as ol from 'ol';

new ol.Map() // but not ol.LayerGroup, for example ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Included in posting. I fixed by using the OpenLayers CDN and not relying on webpack to load ol. The following is the Resources for the page that does NOT work. ol (openlayers) is there.

[image: Resources for page that does not work]